# Microsoft graph api list message count based on category color returns incorrect odata count when using PowerShell

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm working on a PowerShell script to retrieve message count based on category color applied to the message. I'm using microsoft graph api to achieve this. When i use microsoft online graph api developer tool to test the request endpoint, i get a correct value for `odata.count`. However when i query the same endpoint uri using powershell i get incorrect value for odata.count(here the endpoint returns total count for all messages in that particular folder).

Below is the snips for the tests.
Querying the endpoint using online microsoft graph api developer tool
[image]

Response from the tool(This is the true value for all messages with category green)
[image]

Request and response value when using powershell to query the same graph uri(This is incorrect value)
[image]

Below is the request call endpoint

```
 $accessToken = "accesstokenhere"
 $mail_user = "emailhere"
 $blue_uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$mail_user/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'Green+category')&count=true"
    
 $blue_resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $blue_uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $accessToken)}
    
 $blue_resp
```

Have assigned all microsoft graph api `mail and mailboxsettings` permissions in the azure ad oauth app that i'm using to get the accesstoken.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell expects that `$filter` is a variable. You need to use the backtick escape character **`** before $filter

```
$blue_uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$mail_user/mailFolders/inbox/messages?`$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'Green+category')&count=true"
```

Comment: That means for each `$variable` in the uri i use backtick, have added backtick for a single variable in a uri with more than one variable, it has not worked, after adding the backtick before each backtick, it has worked. Thank you